# how can my code understand that function and timeout is running?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want my button to get disabled after clicking only once and if `timeOut` is running it to get disabled, I wrote code if my `moneyValue` is > `money` button to be able to click and it works totally fine, and now in that if statement I want to add `?? (//if function is running)` button to be disabled any ideas ?

here's the code:

```js
  data:{
    crashValue: 1,
    money: 1000,
    moneyValue: 0,
    betAmount: 0,
    buttonDisabled: false
  },
methods:{
    placeBet(){
      let asd = this.money - this.moneyValue;
      this.money = asd;
      this.betAmount = 1000 - asd;
      this.startTimer();
    },
    checkAmount(){
      if(this.moneyValue > this.money // I WANT HELP HERE !){
        this.buttonDisabled = true;
      }else{
        this.buttonDisabled = false;
      }
    },
    startTimer () {
      let interval = 90
      if (this.crashValue > 2.15) {
        interval = 80
      }
      if (this.crashValue > 3.15) {
        interval = 70
      }
      if (this.crashValue > 4) {
        interval = 60
      }
      if (this.crashValue > 6.15) {
        interval = 55
      }
      if (this.crashValue > 8) {
        interval = 48
      }
      if (this.crashValue > 10) {
        interval = 35
      }
      if (this.crashValue > 15) {
        interval = 26
      }
      if (this.crashValue > 22) {
        interval = 16
      }
      var tessst = setTimeout(this.crashFunction, interval);
    },
    placeBet(){
      let asd = this.money - this.moneyValue;
      this.money = asd;
      this.betAmount = 1000 - asd;
      this.startTimer();
    },
    checkAmount2(){
      if(this.moneyValue <= 0 ){
        this.buttonDisabled = true;
      }else{
        this.buttonDisabled = false;
      }
    },
    cashOut(){
      clearTimeout(this.tessst)
      console.log(Number(this.betAmount * this.crashValue).toFixed(2))
    }}
```

```html
          <input @keyup="checkAmount(); checkAmount2()" v-model="moneyValue" class="numbImp" type="number" />
          <p>
            Your bet {{ betAmount }}
          </p>
          <button class="placeBet" :disabled="buttonDisabled" @click="placeBet(); checkAmount(); checkAmount2">Place bet</button>
          <button class="stopCrash" @click="cashOut">Cash out</button>
          <p>
            You currently have {{ money }} money
          </p>
```

Comment: Where are you setting time out? Can you show?

Comment: @NafeesAnwar Done

Answer (score 0):

in your timeout function you have to set a new flag for example `this.functionIsRunning` to `true` and when you clear the timeout function you have to set it  `this.functionIsRunning` to `false`. You did not show your timeout but like this it should work. Adjust your code like following:

```
data:{
    crashValue: 1,
    money: 1000,
    moneyValue: 0,
    betAmount: 0,
    buttonDisabled: false,
    functionIsRunning: false

  },
methods:{
    placeBet(){
      let asd = this.money - this.moneyValue;
      this.money = asd;
      this.betAmount = 1000 - asd;
      this.startTimer();
    },
    checkAmount(){
      if(this.moneyValue > this.money && this.functionIsRunning // I WANT HELP HERE !){
        this.buttonDisabled = true;
      }else{
        this.buttonDisabled = false;
      }
    },
    checkAmount2(){
      if(this.moneyValue <= 0 ){
        this.buttonDisabled = true;
      }else{
        this.buttonDisabled = false;
      }
    },
    cashOut(){
      clearTimeout(this.tessst)
this.functionIsRunning = false;
      console.log(Number(this.betAmount * this.crashValue).toFixed(2))
    }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well i would do it with an computed property here, something like this:

```
<button :disabled="checkMoney">My button</button>
```

And the script:

```
computed: {
   checkMoney:function(){
      return this.moneyValue > this.money && this.functionIsRunning ? true : false; 
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can save if the timeout is set or not by saving the return value. Then create a computed property based on your logic to disable the button.

```
data () {
  return {
    money: 1000,
    moneyValue: 0,
    timeout: null
  }
},

computed: {
  disableButton () {
    return timeout !== null || moneyValue > money
  }
},

methods: {
  startTimer () {
    ...
    this.timeout = setTimeout(this.crashFunction, interval)
  },
  cashOut () {
    clearTimeout(this.timeout)
    this.timeout = null
  }
}
```

And in template

```
<button :disabled="disableButton">Button</button>
```